# How to copy files referenced in array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, copy

I have following Array with filenames. Array is saved under var $files.

```
array ( 
 [0] => DSC02425.jpg 
 [1] => DSC02426.jpg 
 [2] => DSC02432.jpg 
 [3] => DSC02437.jpg 
)
```

I want to copy this files from one to another folder, but how can i achive this?
I made a function but it isnt working:

```
function copyFiles($array) {
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i ++) {
        copy("./" . $array[$i] , "/$folderlabel/" . $array[$i]);
    }
}

copyFiles($files);
```

Comment: what does "isn't working" mean? what's (not) happening? any error messages you get?

Comment: Sorry, here's the Error: `Warning: copy(//KG002-DSC02425.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /volume1/web/www/pindex/index.php` etc

Comment: well then, learn from that error and try to correct it, start by ensuring you do have access to the given folder / file...

Comment: ...and include this in your original post pls, make sure you add it's an edit, otherwise the already given answer may become obsolete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected function:

```
function copyFiles($array,$sourcePath,$savePath) {
for($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++){
    copy($sourcePath.$array[$i],$savePath.$array[$i]);}
}
```

Comment: Do *not* use `global`. Pass it as a function parameter instead: `function copyFiles($array,$folderlabel) { ... }`, and call your function like so: `copyFiles($files, $folderlabel);`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1438393) for why `global`s are evil.

Comment: Yes, make it a parameter. As well as the beginning ("`./`") so you can specify the working directory that function operates on. Otherwise if your script is called from a different working directory, it will crash again.

Comment: @user2987790: Also take care that [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) has a return value. Check it and deal with errors.